# TokenAccountNotFoundError encountered while trying to create token account

Tags: reactjs, solana-web3js

I have been followind solana buildspace and I am currently on core 2, but I'm stuck on "mint token on solana". I keep getting the error TokenAccountNotFoundError. I followed the exact steps on the buildspace, parharps, a change might have been implemeted. This is my code.

```
import { initializeKeypair } from "./initializeKeypair"
import * as token from "@solana/spl-token"
import * as web3 from '@solana/web3.js'

async function createNewMint(
    connection: web3.Connection,
    payer: web3.Keypair,
    mintAuthority: web3.PublicKey,
    freezeAuthority: web3.PublicKey,
    decimals: number
): Promise<web3.PublicKey> {

    const tokenMint = await token.createMint(
        connection,
        payer,
        mintAuthority,
        freezeAuthority,
        decimals
    );

    console.log(`The token mint account address is ${tokenMint}`)
    console.log(
        `Token Mint: https://explorer.solana.com/address/${tokenMint}?cluster=devnet`
    );

    return tokenMint;
}

async function createTokenAccount(
  connection: web3.Connection,
  payer: web3.Keypair,
  mint: web3.PublicKey,
  owner: web3.PublicKey
) {
  const tokenAccount = await token.getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
      connection,
      payer,
      mint,
      owner
  )
  
  console.log(
      `Token Account: https://explorer.solana.com/address/${tokenAccount.address}?cluster=devnet`
  )

  return tokenAccount
}


async function mintTokens(
  connection: web3.Connection,
  payer: web3.Keypair,
  mint: web3.PublicKey,
  destination: web3.PublicKey,
  authority: web3.Keypair,
  amount: number
) {
  const mintInfo = await token.getMint(connection, mint)

  const transactionSignature = await token.mintTo(
    connection,
    payer,
    mint,
    destination,
    authority,
    amount * 10 ** mintInfo.decimals
  )

  console.log(
    `Mint Token Transaction: https://explorer.solana.com/tx/${transactionSignature}?cluster=devnet`
  )
}

async function main() {
  const connection = new web3.Connection(web3.clusterApiUrl("devnet"))
  const user = await initializeKeypair(connection)

  console.log("PublicKey:", user.publicKey.toBase58())

  const mint = await createNewMint(
    connection,
    user,           // We'll pay the fees
    user.publicKey, // We're the mint authority
    user.publicKey, // And the freeze authority >:)
    2               // Only two decimals!
  )

  const tokenAccount = await createTokenAccount(
    connection,     
    user,           
    mint,            
    user.publicKey   // Associating our address with the token account
  )
  
  // Mint 100 tokens to our address
  await mintTokens(connection, user, mint, tokenAccount.address, user, 100)
}

main()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Finished successfully")
    process.exit(0)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
    process.exit(1)
  })
```

I've tried checking for the solution on google, but I couldn't find much help.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, so the error is because we are not waiting for the confirmed state of the account creation, and there seems to be a couple of seconds lag on the network. Here is a solution you can use.

```
  const connection = new web3.Connection(web3.clusterApiUrl("devnet"), {
    commitment: "confirmed",
  });
```

This will ensure your networks wait for a "confirmed" state before proceeding thereby fixing the issue.